Movie search: couple being hunted in the woods by what turn out to be children/teens in the end?
I just remember the movie slightly, a couple drives up to camp in the woods or something and suddenly they start getting hunted by some unknown people. These people in the end turn out to be children/teens and I think the couple didn’t know until the women killed one of them.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

It sounds like Eden Lake (2008) starring Jack O'Connell, Michael Fassbender and Thomas Turgoose among others. 
Synopsis

During a romantic weekend getaway, a young couple confronts a gang of
  youths, and suffers brutal consequences.

Eden Lake Poster
